# XPath 3.1 expression to collect attributes as name/value maps for each selected node

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon, xpath-3.1

XPath 3.1 supports a new *map* feature that allows maps in the result sequences.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps

For example, here is the valid XPath 3.1 expression that returns a hardcoded sequence of 2 maps:

```
(map {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, map {'x':-3,'y':-2,'z':-1})
```

I am trying to use this feature to collect node attributes as list of maps.

For example, for the given xml:

```
<root>
  <node a="1" b="2" c="3"/>
  <node x="-3" y="-2" z="-1"/>
</root>
```

How can I craft a simple XPath expression to get the following result:

```
[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, {'x':-3,'y':-2,'z':-1}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an element as context item you can form a map of the attributes like this:

```
map:merge(@* ! map{local-name(): string()})
```

To get a sequence of maps for a sequence of elements $in, you can do

```
$in ! map:merge(@* ! map{local-name(): string()})
```

To get an array of maps for a sequence of elements $in, you can do

```
array { $in ! map:merge(@* ! map{local-name(): string()}) }
```

In your example you are also converting the attribute values to numbers, so you would use `xs:integer(.)` in place of `string()`. But you haven't said what you want to do if there are non-numeric attributes.

Comment: I am getting net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Namespace prefix 'map' has not been declared. Am I missing some configuration? I am using s9api java api and i am calling xpathCompiler.setLanguageVersion("3.1");

Comment: Nevermind figured i have to call: xpathCompiler.declareNamespace("map", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map");  Checking the rest of the solution now

Comment: For my needs the following expression was sufficient: ```/root/node/map:merge(@*/map{local-name(): xs:integer(.)})```

Wonder if there is any performance hit of using '/' vs '!'.

Comment: The compiler will work out that if the RHS of "/" isn't going to return nodes, then it can safely replace the "/" by the simpler "!" operator. But I prefer to use "!" to start with, since it better reflects the intent.